# Getting Grails version from within plugin _install.groovy script

Tags: grails, plugins

One of my plugins needs to behave differently for grails 1.x and 2.x. So I would like to switch based on the grails version used to install the plugin, but I didn't find a way to get the grails version...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grails.util.Metadata.current.getGrailsVersion()`. Note that you cannot use the property-access variant (`grails.util.Metadata.current.grailsVersion`) because `Metadata` is a `Map` and this will look for the property stored under the key `"grailsVersion"` and return null since it's stored under `"app.grails.version"`.

Answer (score 1):

To check your grails version:

```
grails -version
```

When installing an older plugin, be sure to configure the version in

```
application.properties
```

in your grails project.